# Examples of semi-norms on the real line

Tags: functional-analysis

I just would like to solicit some examples of semi-norms on the set $\mathbb{R}$? Of course, one such examples is the absolute value function. Are there any examples?

Comment: This is immediate from the definition.

Comment: Sir David, what i want is an example of a semi-norm on $\mathbb{R}$ other than the absolute value function.

Comment: What makes you think I didn't understand what you want?

Comment: an explicit example of a semi-norm other than the absolute value function?

Comment: Is "an explicit example of a semi-norm other than the absolute value function?" actually an answer to the question "What makes you think I didn't understand what you want?" ? (Hint: no.)

Comment: @juniven: See my answer.

Comment: The family of seminorms on $\mathbb{R}$ is rather boring. $\{ x \mapsto c\cdot \lvert x\rvert : c \in [0,+\infty)\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, we have the function $\lvert \lvert x \rvert \rvert=0$.